# Where do I put .js files in Max/MSP?

Tags: javascript, libraries, philips-hue, max-msp-jitter

Where do I put .js files in Max?

I am currently using help from this thread on the Cycling forum to link Philips Hue lighting with Max 7.

https://cycling74.com/forums/topic/controlling-philips-hue-using-jython-and-phue/ and currently trying to use this method. https://gist.github.com/tgck/11185861#file-huerequestbuilder-js

I have got the patch in my patcher window but I don't know where to put the .js (HueRequestBuidler.js) file that it needs to run. Where do I put this file for Max to be able to read it and link with the patch?

I'm sure this has been asked before but I searched and couldn't find any answers that helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

You typically place js files in the same folder as your patch. There should be a [js HueRequestBuidler] object in the patch that uses it.

Answer (score 3):

Add the folder containing your .js files to the Max search path in Options/File Preferences.  You can find more documentation [here](https://docs.cycling74.com/max5/vignettes/core/file_preferences_window.html).